# Know which (exact) R version a package was built under?

Tags: r, cran, roxygen2

How can we tell precisely which R version an R package was built under?

#### Example

In the RSelenium package's `DESCRIPTION` file [here](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/blob/master/DESCRIPTION), we see

```
Depends:
    R (>= 3.0.0)
```

But this does not appear to be precise (due to the `>` symbol)

#### Notes

Karl Browman's site [says](https://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/depends.html) that:

> Depends is used to indicate dependency on a particular version of R, and on packages that are to be loaded (with library()) whenever your package is loaded. If you expect that users would want to load that other package whenever they loaded yours, then you should include the package name here. But this is now relatively rare. (I think the namespaces for these packages should also be imported, with @import.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It almost never matters which version built a package.  The only thing that usually matters is which version installed it.  (Binary packages are images of installed packages, so it matters for them.)

The version that installed a package is stored in the `Built:` field in the `DESCRIPTION` file.  (Yes, "Built", not "Installed".)
You can see it using code like

```r
read.dcf(system.file("DESCRIPTION", package="base"), fields="Built")
#>      Built                                     
#> [1,] "R 3.6.1; ; 2019-07-06 02:01:41 UTC; unix"
```

Put in your own package name instead of `"base"`.

The exception for the "almost never matters" is on those rare occasions when the package format changes.

Comment: Great answer. Interestingly, the result of `read.dcf(system.file("DESCRIPTION", package="RSelenium"), fields="Built")` is `[1,] "R 3.6.0; ; 2019-04-27 03:05:58 UTC; unix"`, yet I cannot see any field for `Built` at [the github source](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/blob/master/DESCRIPTION), which is kinda strange?

Comment: That field is added when it is installed.